# Civi Error loading homepage

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

I am getting this message when I load my website. Is this a Civi Issue?

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/aflbs/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:305) in /home/aflbs/www/www/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1216

Answer (score 3):

I changed my cache plugin and that seemed to fix the problem.